# Unity perlin noise having repeating patterns

Tags: unity-game-engine, perlin-noise

I made a Noise class using the Perlin Noise from Unity like this:

```
public static float[,] GetNoise(Vector2Int initialOffset, float scale, float persistance, float lacunarity, int octaves)
    {
        float[,] noiseMap = new float[Chunk.width, Chunk.height];
        float maxHeight = 0;
        float minHeight = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < Chunk.height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Chunk.width; x++)
            {
                float amplitude = 1;
                float frequency = 1;
                float noiseHeight = 0;

                for (int oc = 0; oc < octaves; oc++)
                {
                    float coordX = (x + initialOffset.x) / scale * frequency;
                    float coordY = (y + initialOffset.y) / scale * frequency;

                    float perlin = Mathf.PerlinNoise(coordX, coordY) * 2 - 1;
                    noiseHeight += perlin * amplitude;

                    amplitude *= persistance;
                    frequency *= lacunarity;
                }

                if (noiseHeight < minHeight)
                {
                    minHeight = noiseHeight;
                }
                if (noiseHeight > maxHeight)
                {
                    maxHeight = noiseHeight;
                }
                noiseMap[x, y] = noiseHeight;
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < Chunk.height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Chunk.width; x++)
            {
                noiseMap[x, y] = Mathf.InverseLerp(minHeight, maxHeight, noiseMap[x, y]);
            }
        }

        return noiseMap;
    }
```

However this code is giving me repeating patterns like this:
[image: Patterns in the Perlin Noise]

What am I doing wrong? Or there is no way to get rid of the patterns?

Comment: Can someone please explain me why dislike this question? Is something wrong?

Comment: Did you try adding noise afterword to add more randomness? See this: https://forum.unity.com/threads/perlin-noise-repeated-values.248132/#post-2129909

Comment: Are you using different values for your x and y offset?

Comment: @Jake Yes the offsets are the distance between the tile and the origin (tile 0, 0) and I calculate that multiplying the size of each chunk by the chunk position

Comment: @Kale_Surfer_Dude I am using octaves, does that count? The settings I am using is 0.5 for persistance, 2 for lacunarity and 4 for the number of octaves and a scale of 12

Comment: @Simplecoder if you add some arbitrary constant to your x and y then the patterning will be less noticeable

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, not very well, but working. The way I did was I generate the height map for every tile in the chunk, then I did some random placing of tiles, while having in account the height map. Something like this:

```
if (heightMap[x, y] < 0.3 && Random.value < 0.5)
    // Add tile
```

This way I got this result:
[image]
EDIT:
Doing some more research about Perlin Noise I found out that it just doesn't like negative coords for some reason, so I did this way, hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

so .. fixed the negative coords like this:

```
//account for negatives (ex. -1 % 256 = -1, needs to loop around to 255)
if (noiseOffset.x < 0)
    noiseOffset = new Vector2(noiseOffset.x + noiseRange.x, noiseOffset.y);
if (noiseOffset.y < 0)
    noiseOffset = new Vector2(noiseOffset.x, noiseOffset.y + noiseRange.y);
```